# Valid question links can't be opened in the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

(I've been meaning to ask this for a while...)

I often view my [Rep Tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx) from my phone, and click on the link there. Unfortunately, when I click on a link to a question, I'm asked which app to use - and if I choose the Stack Exchange app, I get an error of "Loading the question failed."

The links in question are formed like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138582
```

The links work fine on the site... can the link parser be updated to handle this?

Comment: Looks like this is happening because the ID on that URL is for an answer and the site is doing a 302 redirect but the app is not. I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report! This is fixed in version 0.1.88 coming out around midnight UTC.